# Book with a female main character living in a convent who has to fight gods

Tags: story-identification, books

In the book, the heroine was living in a convent, but then some gods became greedy for power and fought the war which caused Jade to be unleashed on the Earth. So she had to travel with companions to restore balance and take back power from the gods. On her way, she met a boy who can shapeshift but cannot talk because his tongue was missing.

Comment: "Jade to be unleashed" - Who is Jade?

Answer (score 17):

Possibly "*The Jade Demons Quartet*" by Robert E. Vardeman (comprising *Quaking Lands*, *Frozen Waves*, *Crystal Clouds* and *White Fire*). From an [entry on Scribd.com](https://www.scribd.com/book/240663037/The-Jade-Demons-Quartet):

> Kesira Minette's world has shattered amid a terrible rain of jade. The magical jade has killed the patron demon of her order and turned ordinary humans into strange werecreatures. Worse, the demons who were not killed have become...insane. She leaves the safety of her cloistered existence, accompanied by a sentient green bird and a tongueless shapeshifter, Molimo.

[image: Book cover: "The Jade Demons Quartet"]

(Image from above website).

Comment: Well spotted. How did you find it?

Comment: Googled "_story shapeshift Jade convent missing tongue_". This question was the top result, the above link was about 6th.

Comment: Is that what nuns look like now?

Comment: Only the ones with patron demons

Comment: .... with the magic let-me-find-that-for-you button.

Comment: It's self-published, so I'm even more impressed that you found it. :-/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read the book about seven years ago but I've been wanting to read it again